# Stored procedure call with an ISNULL in the assignment. Invalid Syntax?

Tags: sql-server, syntax, isnull

Above the call to this stored procedure is another call to a different stored procedure. The first procedure will assign something to `@NewIdentifier` if it needs to, otherwise I need to use the default `SaleId`.

```
exec myStoredProc @SaleId = ISNULL(@NewIdentifier, @SaleId)
```

It works if I do it this way

```
declare @Id int
set @Id = ISNULL(@NewIdentifier, @SaleId)
exec myStoredProc @SaleId = @Id
```

Is it possible to use `ISNULL` in the assignment of a stored procedure parameter? I'm not sure what is invalid about this syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parameter must be a constant or a variable. It cannot be an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the '=' operator has lower precedence than '(' ?  If so, it would be parsed as **exec myStoredProc (@SaleId = ISNULL) (@NewIdentifier, @SaleId)**, which would be a syntax error.